# BUG when rendering data by category in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, real-time-data

So, i have a dynamic data from redux state...this data can be delete by user and show the realtime data.

I make a filter button for my data (all, frontend, backend).Actually about 50% it works, i can see the data when the category is changing...but when i am in ex. frontend (filter) than i delete some data from that, then all the data show(without deleted data) although the filter still in frontend.

check the website on favorite page, add to favorite some packages first.

[installing-app.vercel.app](https://installing-app.vercel.app/)

```
const dataPackages = useSelector((state) => state.favorite.packages);
const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState([])
const [favoritesPkg, setFavoritesPkg] = useState([]);
const [category, setCategory] = useState("all")

 // load data from local
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect", category)
    setDefaultData(dataPackages)
    setFavoritesPkg(dataPackages)
}, [dataPackages])

const handleSelectedCategory = (e) => {
    setCategory(e.target.value)
        if(e.target.value == "all"){
            setFavoritesPkg(defaultData)
        }else{
            const filteredData = defaultData.filter(pkg => pkg.type == e.target.value)
            setFavoritesPkg(filteredData)
        }
}

return(...
<select className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 px-2" onChange={handleSelectedCategory}>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="frontend">Frontend</option>
    <option value="backend">Backend</option>
</select>

 <div className="lg:flex mx-auto lg:flex-wrap gap-x-5 justify-center">
    {favoritesPkg?.map((pkg) => (
    <FavoriteCode data={pkg} key={pkg.id} />
    ))}
</div>
```

when the filter is in frontend, then i delete some data from those, i see the realtime data of frontend not all the data.